# Python post calls are not working

Tags: python, http, post

I have a server running at :

```
http://localhost:3000/appleconnect
```

which will accept post calls. So I have written the python code for making http request, but that doesn't work:

```
import httplib, urllib, json
params = json.load("{'op' : 'sign'}")
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",
           "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost:3000")
conn.request("POST", "/appleconnect",
             params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
conn.close()
```

The above is not working. It gives me the error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post.py", line 2, in <module>
    params = json.load("{'op' : 'sign'}")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: What is "application/application/json"?

Comment: Sorry updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`.
As for the second error, you have to make sure your string is a json object first. Try this code:

```
import httplib, urllib, json
jsonObject = json.dumps("{'op' : 'sign'}")
params = json.loads(jsonObject)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.load` is for files or file-like objects. For a plain dict, you need `json.loads`.

**Edit**

Your string is not valid JSON: for that you need double quotes, not single ones.

But I do not understand why you are doing this at all. It is the wrong way round: `loads` converts a JSON string to Python objects, but `conn.request` expects a string in the first place. I suspect you wanted to start with a Python dict, convert it to JSON, and then pass that to the request:

```
params = json.dumps({'op' : 'sign'})
```

Comment: now getting the following error: `File "post.py", line 2, in <module>
    params = json.loads("{operation : 'signout'}")
  . . . 
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`